# How to access all child methods using one single object?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

I have a query : 
we can access all methods from child class using down casting
consider following code
Base Class :

```
public class BaseClass {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Base class");
    }
}
```

ChildOne :

```
public class ChildOne extends BaseClass {
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("inside ChildOne");
    }
}
```

ChildTwo:

```
public class ChildTwo extends BaseClass {

    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("inside ChildTwo");
    }
}
```

And client class

```
try {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add(new BaseClass());
    l.add(new ChildOne());
    l.add(new ChildTwo());

    for (Object o : l) {
        BaseClass bc = (BaseClass) Class.forName(o.getClass().getName().toString()).newInstance();
        bc.method();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}

outPut :

Base class
inside ChildOne
inside ChildTwo
```

now the question what if

```
public abstract class BaseClass {

        public abstract void method(); 
    }
```

as we cannot create object of either interface or of abstract class.
In above code I'm able to access all methods from all classes. 
Consider we've interface named `BaseClass` with method definition as I am I'm implementing that interface in many classes now the question is how I can access all methods without creating particular instance of every class
**I want to do that in single loop** but inheritance won't allow us
**How to do that?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a list with generic type (`BaseClass`): `List<BaseClass> l = new ArrayList<>();`

Polymorphism is in action, the loop will look like:

```
for (BaseClass o : l) o.method();
```

Comment: here BaseClass is **abstract** Class and Method is **abstract** too

Comment: @holidayCoder, yes, but the list will contain completed implementations of `BaseClass` which implement all abstract methods from the parent